# Ruby metaprogramming: accessing class name

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm fairly new to Ruby metaprogramming. I'm trying to write code which generates the 
"dup" function for a class when it's created, using a list of fields which should be passed into the constructor. However, I can't figure out how to get access to the name of the class I'm creating, while I'm creating it.

So for example, if I had this code:

```
class Example
  make_dup :name, :value
  attr_accessor :name, :value

  def initialize(name,value)
    @name, @value = name, value
  end
end
```

I'd want it to create the method:

```
def dup
  Example.new(name,value)
end
```

I'm just getting stuck on how it would figure out to insert `Example` there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by generating the `dup` method for the class, considering that it inherits `Class#dup`. As far as obtaining the class object, `self` equals `Example` as soon as `class Example` is parsed.  You can verify that with a `puts`.

Comment: You've answered my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that all classes have built-in `dup` and `clone` methods. You can customize what happens in them by adding an `initialize_copy` method, e.g.:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
  def initialize_copy(orig)
    super
    @bar = @bar.dup
  end
end
```

In case that isn't what you're truly looking for, you can access an object's class using its class method:

```
class Foo
  def p_class
    p self.class      # Foo.new.p_class => Foo     ; self is *a* `Foo'
  end

  def self.p_class
    p self.class      # Foo.p_class     => Class   ; self *is* `Foo'
  end
end
```

Comment: not like you need the extra points but this is a really good answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def dup
  self.class.new(name,value)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement it this way:

```
module MyDup
  def make_dup(*args)
    define_method(:my_dup) do
      obj = self.class.new(nil, nil)
      args.each do |arg|
        obj.send(arg.to_s + "=", self.send(arg))
      end
      obj
    end
  end
end

class Example
  extend MyDup
  make_dup :name, :value
  attr_accessor :name, :value

  def initialize(name,value)
    @name, @value = name, value
  end
end

e = Example.new("John", 30)
p e

d = e.my_dup
p d
```

Execution result as follows:

```
#<Example:0x000000022325d8 @name="John", @value=30>
#<Example:0x00000002232358 @name="John", @value=30>
```